# Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the data from JSON URL my data have array within array of JSON, I am pretty new here so please give me the suggestion how i read the data..Thanks..

here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Privacy Policy</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showdata"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

var url = "http://portal.entitledirect.com/test/entitle_news.php";
var data = {"news_type": "docs","dt":"1417222458109"};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data:data,
    dataType: "jsonp",
     contentType:    'application/json',
    type: 'GET',
    jsonpCallback: 'methodCaa',

    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (item, value) {
            if (item == "rates") {
                $.each($.parseJSON(value), function (i, object) {
                    console.log(i + "=" + object);
                });
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR));
            console.log( textStatus );   console.log( errorThrown );
    }

});



});

function methodCaa(data){
    console.log((data));

}





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the time of read the values from JSON i get the error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of nulljquery-1.7.1.min.js:2    e.extend.eachjsonindex.html:25 $.ajax.successjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 njquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 wjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 d.onload.d.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: Please post the structure of `result`...

Comment: @krillgar jQuery could be using it internally...

Comment: Don't use `$.parseJSON()`; the result is already parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Having no idea about the nature of ajax result and what you are trying to do, here is the correct syntax for processing the response :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Privacy Policy</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showdata"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$showdata = $('#showdata');
$(function(){
    var url = "http://portal.entitledirect.com/test/entitle_news.php";
    var data = {"news_type": "docs","dt":"1417222458109"};
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data:data,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType:    'application/json',
        type: 'GET',
        jsonpCallback: 'methodCaa',

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function (item, value) {
                console.log("Processing index "+ item);
                //if (item == "rates") {
                    $.each(value, function (i, object) {
                        $.each(object, function(j, objectValue){
                            console.log(j, objectValue);
                            $showdata.append(j +": "+objectValue+"<br />");
                        });
                    });
                //}
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR));
                console.log( textStatus );   console.log( errorThrown );
        }

    });
});
function methodCaa(data){
    console.log((data));

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```